# React Native once user opens screen don't recharge it everytime

Tags: reactjs, navigation, native

I have and aplication that fetches info when the screen loads, i want the app that once one screen has been charged for first time and fetched all the data, the next time i comeback to that same screed all is already charged so its way smoother. Any help would be apreciated. Thanks.

Comment: you need to provide code to get answer for your problem.

Comment: My code is more than 1000 lines every .js but i definitely can explan more detailed. For example i have a page with diferent films fetched from an api and when i click any film it opens a new view with the info of that film, also fetched from an api. What i want, is that when i comeback from the film info to the film list, it doesn't fetch again all the films so the user stays all day waiting to check some films. Something like keeping the fetch in a variable or keeping the films view in background not closing it.